# What happens if you have more than 7 cards in your hand at the end of a turn in Jaipur?

Tags: jaipur

The rules state that you cannot have more than 7 cards in your hand at the end of a turn. Does this mean you're not allowed to play in such a way that you have more than 7 cards, or do you have to discard cards down to 7 at the end of the turn?

For example if you have 6 cards in your hand and you trade 2 camels for 2 goods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not take an action that causes you to have more than 7 cards in your hand.  If you have 7 cards in hand, then you cannot draw 1 card from the market or trade camels for cards from the market.  And you also can't trade more camels for cards from the market than you have hand space available.  So in your example, if you have 6 cards in hand, you cannot trade 2 camels for 2 goods.

Comment: Nice answer! This situation leads to some interesting strategy, since if your opponent has a lot of cards in their hand, you can purposefully leave available some high value cards that they won't be able to take.

Comment: Duncan: your opponent could exchange cards from his hands with cards from the board. So your plan may backfire.